# Use list of indices to manipulate a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to perform operations on a nested dictionary (data retrieved from a yaml file):

```
data = {'services': {'web': {'name': 'x'}}, 'networks': {'prod': 'value'}}
```

I'm trying to modify the above using the inputs like:

```
{'services.web.name': 'new'}
```

I converted the above to a list of indices `['services', 'web', 'name']`. But I'm not able to/not sure how to perform the below operation in a loop:

```
data['services']['web']['name'] = new
```

That way I can modify dict the data. There are other values I plan to change in the above dictionary (it is extensive one) so I need a solution that works in cases where I have to change, EG:

```
data['services2']['web2']['networks']['local'].
```

Is there a easy way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may iterate over the keys while moving a reference:

```
data = {'networks': {'prod': 'value'}, 'services': {'web': {'name': 'x'}}}
modification = {'services.web.name': 'new'}

for key, value in modification.items():
    keyparts = key.split('.')
    to_modify = data
    for keypart in keyparts[:-1]:
        to_modify = to_modify[keypart]
    to_modify[keyparts[-1]] = value

print(data)
```

Giving:

```
{'networks': {'prod': 'value'}, 'services': {'web': {'name': 'new'}}}
```

Comment: Awesome. I was able to get it working with some modifications! Appreciate the help.